# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in Google Sheets Apps Script Tutorial

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm following a tutorial for Google Sheets Apps Scripts editor, and I'm on module 4.  There is a problem with the code that I copied and pasted from the module verbatim, and I'm not sure how to correct it.  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
My best guess is that there is a stray '<' somewhere that needs to be removed, but performing a search doesn't turn up anything, so I'm thinking it might be a problem with the responseText that JSON is retrieving.  The error occurs here, at line 94:

```
function fetchApiResourceObject_(url) {
  // Make request to API and get response.
  var response =
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});

  // Parse and return the response as a JSON object.
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var responseObject = JSON.parse(json); 
  return responseObject; 
}
```

The full code is here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-4/#6

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify the response from response.getContextText(), it may be returning a different format than what you expect.

Mozilla reference a `getAs` method: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getAs(String), I'm unsure if this would be helpful in this case.

I'd recommend adding a few console.logs, check what the URL is, check the JSON is actually JSON.

Comment: i.e. It is most likely returning HTML or even XML. Some servers return a “200” HTML error page :(