# Extracting Shopify Report via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to automatically import our shopify report into Google Sheets via shopify API. My code currently looks like this:

```
function importShopifyReport() {
  var shopUrl = 'shop.myshopify.com';
  var apiKey = 'xxx';
  var apiPassword = 'xxx';
  var spreadsheetId = 'spreadsheet'; 
  var sheetName = 'test';
  //var store_url = 'https://shop.myshopify.com/admin/reports/2739306761'

  var url = 'https://shop.myshopify.com/admin/reports/2739306761';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    "method": "GET",
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'header': {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("apiKey:apiPassword")
        }
    });

  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var headers = Object.keys(data.results[0]);
  var values = data.results.map(function(item) {
    return headers.map(function(header) {
      return item[header];
    });
  });

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

And the error code is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<html>
  <"... is not valid JSON
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm also open to any other good solution for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe similar to this question ([SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in Google Sheets Apps Script Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691932/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-in-google-sheets-apps-scri)), you want to verify that you are actually receiving a JSON object from the shopify API.

The error is coming from the `JSON.parse`. By calling `JSON.parse` you are basically saying that you 100% guarantee that `response.getContentText()` is just stringified json and nothing else, which has a certain predictable structure to it (ie it always has opening and closing curly braces, etc). The error is telling you that it is attempting to parse what is supposed to be a stringified json, but it is encountering unexpected characters. In this case, it looks like it is receiving a full HTML document (which always starts with opening angle brackets).

I'm not familiar with the shopify API, but I would console log `response.getContentText()` to make sure it aligns with their documentation. It's possible that instead of a JSON you are getting an HTML error page, perhaps indicating that you are using the incorrect credentials or something like that. Just from skimming through their API docs, it looks like their API endpoints include `api` in the URL path, so it's possible you are not hitting their API, but rather an HTML page instead.